# How to run a search that returns after a certain amount of time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that runs an iterative deepening search and would like to return the value from the deepest search after a certain amount of time has passed. The code skeleton would look something like

```
import time

answers = []
START = time.clock()
current_depth = 1

while time.clock() - START < DESIRED_RUN_TIME:
    answers.append(IDS(depth=current_depth))
    current_depth += 1

return answers[-1]
```

The problem with this code is it will not return until after the time limit has passed. What is the best way to solve this? If I should just add time checks in the IDS function, how can I make sure to return the last value found? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For a search problem I kept a global "best" answer and the search branches updated it as they found a better one.  If you have a single thread doing the search you won't run into thread safety issues otherwise you need locking / critical section / whatever to update best.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work unless `IDS` is blocking and takes a very long time. Then you have to wait until IDS is finished and the time limit may not be all that precise.

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by

> would like to return the value from the deepest search after a certain amount of time has passed.

and

> The problem with this code is it will not return until after the time limit has passed.

If you have time limits and you have update times then you can use this code as a generator.

```
import time

answers = []
START = time.clock()
current_depth = 1

def get_ids(update_time, limit_time):
    last_update = time.clock()
    while time.clock() - START < DESIRED_RUN_TIME:
        answers.append(IDS(depth=current_depth))
        current_depth += 1
        if time.clock() - last_update < update_time:
            last_update = time.clock()
            yield answers[-1]

    yield answers[-1]

for i in get_ids(1, 10):  # get an ids every second and stop after 10 seconds
    print(i)
```